# How to print Alphabets using UDF Scalar function?

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, user-defined-functions

I am trying to print Alphabets by creating UDF scalar function. 
Here is my code:

```
create function [dbo].[fnalphabets]()
returns varchar
as begin
declare @num int=65
 while(@num<=90)
 begin
 set @num=@num+1
 end
  return char(@num)
 end
```

when I am calling this function using

```
select dbo.fnalphabets()
```

It doesn't returns expected result. could anyone let me know what is wrong with my code?

Comment: What is expected output

Comment: I want to print alphabets from A to Z

Comment: you're looping through all but returning only one at the end from function!

Comment: Yes, but how to print all ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: I changed its return varchar size here and declare variable to Store the alphabet string. and storing char values in it in while loop. as below and return the same alphabet string.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnalphabets]()
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
AS BEGIN
  DECLARE @num INT=65
  DECLARE @Alphabates VARCHAR(100)=''
  WHILE(@num<=90)
  BEGIN
    SET @Alphabates=@Alphabates+char(@num)
    SET @num=@num+1
  END
  RETURN @Alphabates
END
```

Comment: Its working fine, But could you please explain the role of @Alphabates

Comment: it's just to hold the return value i.e. a-z letters which you will print in calling code.

Comment: @JaydipJ I want to ask one more thing that is, we can hold the values using `@num` and return its values by `return char(@num`) but why it doesn't work like `@Alphabates` ?

Comment: and why we use `VARCHAR(100)=''` in  `DECLARE @Alphabates VARCHAR(100)=''` ? as we can simply use  `DECLARE @Alphabates VARCHAR(100)` to hold the values

Comment: yes, but it returns `NULL` when I am using only `DECLARE @Alphabates VARCHAR(100)`

Comment: Yes I mean both syntax are correct. In our case we need to initialize this variable to empty string. so that it can allow to append char to it

Answer (score 2):

No need of **Loop** or **Function** anything. Just take `Spt_Values` table from `master` database for numbers and do cast them to `Char`

```
SELECT CHAR(number)
FROM master.dbo.spt_values
WHERE type = 'p'
    AND NUMBER BETWEEN 65
        AND 90
ORDER BY NUMBER
```

**Edit:**
From Comments : UDF for the above code

```
Go
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fnalphabets]()
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
AS BEGIN
    DECLARE @Alphabates VARCHAR(130)='';
    SELECT  @Alphabates = @Alphabates +CHAR(number) +'
    '
    FROM master.dbo.spt_values
    WHERE type = 'p'
    AND NUMBER BETWEEN 65
        AND 90
    ORDER BY NUMBER

    RETURN @Alphabates
END
```

Comment: Yes, but i want to do it by using scalar UDF

Comment: Put the above select in a function. And call it @JasonClark

Answer (score 1):

**TRY THIS**: you can use `Table Valued Functions` as below, it will give you each A-Z in separate rows:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnalphabets]()
RETURNS @list TABLE (alphabet VARCHAR(10))
BEGIN
    DECLARE @num INT=65
     WHILE(@num<=90)
     BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @list SELECT CHAR(@num)
        SET @num=@num+1
     END

      RETURN
END

SELECT * FROM [dbo].[fnalphabets]()
```